# Why does not Xamarin bind property?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin

I want to save data to application on window closing or application crashes.

When user writes to entry the data gets storen in property, but for some reason the binding does not work.

I followed a course on Udemy for this. I think it has something to do with referencing to different place in PCL.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace TheIVInventory.ViewModels
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class AddItemPage : ContentPage
    {
        public AddItemPage()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = Application.Current;


        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) //Item added click.
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Xaml :

```
<ContentPage 
     BackgroundColor="#104850"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="TheIVInventory.ViewModels.AddItemPage">

    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" x:Name="formLayout" Margin="20">
        <Entry  PlaceholderColor="White" Keyboard="Chat" Margin="40" Placeholder="Item Name" TextColor="White" Text="{Binding ItemName}"></Entry>
        <Entry PlaceholderColor="White" Keyboard="Numeric" Margin="40" Placeholder="Item Price MIN (€)" TextColor="White"></Entry>
        <Entry PlaceholderColor="White" Keyboard="Numeric" Margin="40" Placeholder="Item Price MAX (€)" TextColor="White"></Entry>
        <Editor PlaceholderColor="White" Margin="40" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Keyboard="Chat" Placeholder="Item Description" TextColor="White"></Editor>
        <Button Text="Save" BackgroundColor="#80EEFF"  Margin="10" Clicked="Button_Clicked" ></Button>
        <Image Source="konjakki.png" Scale="0.15" AnchorY="0" BackgroundColor="#104850" ></Image>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace TheIVInventory
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        // Setting the item add members.
        private const string itemNameKey = "Name";
        private const string itemMinPrice = "0";

        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage())
            {
                BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#104850"),
                BarTextColor = Color.White


            }; // Making the navigation possible.
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }

        // Making the add item properties.

        public string ItemName
        {
            get
            {
                if (Properties.ContainsKey(itemNameKey))
                    return Properties[itemNameKey].ToString();

                return "";
            }
            set
            {
                Properties[ItemName] = value;
            }
        }

        public string ItemMinPrice
        {
            get
            {
                if (Properties.ContainsKey(itemMinPrice))
                    return Properties[itemMinPrice].ToString();

                return "";
            }
            set
            {
                Properties[itemMinPrice] = value;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting `Application.Current` as your `BindingContext`?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you don't appear to have set a BindingContext for your XAML to refer to.

It also looks to me as if you are trying to implement MVVM structure, but have not entirely understood it.

The points that immediately draw my eye are:

- Your view code is within a ViewModel namespace rather than View
  (which will prove confusing later on).
- You have code that should be within a ViewModel class (which will be your Views BindingContext) in your main App code.

I would suggest that you create a Views namespace and move your AddItemPage code to it;
Create an AddItemViewModel and use it to implement your ItemName and ItemMinPrice properties.
Instead of using a button_clicked event in the code behind, bind the Button Command to an ICommand property type in your ViewModel. Then have your ViewModel instantiate the ICommand to use an internal method to run your save code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve the MVVM in xamarin forms. Your binding way is wrong, you could create a model, put the `ItemMinPrice` and `ItemName` in this model like following code.Achieve the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, when data was changed.

```
  class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    string itemMinPrice;
    public string ItemMinPrice
    {
        set
        {
            if (itemMinPrice != value)
            {
                itemMinPrice = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ItemMinPrice");

            }
        }
        get
        {
            return itemMinPrice;
        }
    }



    string itemName;
    public string ItemName
    {
        set
        {
            if (itemName != value)
            {
                itemName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ItemName");

            }
        }
        get
        {
            return itemName;
        }
    }

}
```

Then you can change the `bindingContext`, like this code `BindingContext = new MyModel();`

I add a break point in the `MyModel`, give a itemName in the Entry you can see it was executed like following GIF.
[image]

Note: If you want to achieve that model data changed could display the view. You should change `Mode` to `TwoWay` like following code.

```
 <Entry  PlaceholderColor="White" Keyboard="Chat" Margin="40" 
   Placeholder="Item Name" TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding ItemName, 
   Mode=TwoWay}"></Entry>
```

[image]

Here is offical artical about MVVM, you can refer to it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm